# how to create a regular expression to validate the numbers are not same even separated by hyphen (-)

Tags: java, regex

Using the following regex

```
^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d{3}-\d{1}$
```

It works for the pattern but I need to validate that all numbers are not the same even after /separated by the hyphen (-).

Example:

```
0000-0 not allowed (because of all are same digits)
0000-1 allowed
1111-1 not allowed (because of all are same digits)
1234-2 allowed
```

Answer (score 2):

You could exclude only `-` or the same digit only to the right till the end of the string:

```
^(\d)(?!(?:\1|-)*$)\d{3}-\d$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d)` Capture group 1, match a digit
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is to the right is not

  - `(?:\1|-)*$` Optionally repeat either the backrefernce to what is already captured or `-` till the end of the string
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\d{3}-\d` Match 3 digits `-` and a digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xL1D0z/1)

If you don't want to match double `--` or an `-` at the end of the string and match optional repetitions:

```
^(\d)(?!(?:\1|-)*$)\d*(?:-\d+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d)` Capture a single digits in group 1
- `(?!(?:\1|-)*$)` Negative lookahead, assert not only `-` and the same digit till the end of the string
- `\d*` Match optional digits
- `(?:-\d+)*` Optionally repeat matching `-` and 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qLoRcw/1)

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird  , as per my requirement updated the regex slightly as ^(\d)(?!(?:\1|-)*$)\d{4}(?:-\d{1})$ as its needed fixed length before and after the -

Comment: @HarinathaReddy Shouldn't it be like this then? `^(\d)(?!(?:\1|-)*$)\d{3}-\d$` https://regex101.com/r/xL1D0z/1

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird, it's really helpful to me. I couldn't understand the part (?!(?:\1|-)*$) mainly the difference ?! and ?: along with | . Could you share me any links to refer this concepts.

Comment: @HarinathaReddy I have updated the answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

[TheFourthBird's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72129684/548225) surely works that uses a negative lookahead. Here is another variant of this regex that might be slightly faster:

```sh
^(\d)(?!\1{3}-\1$)\d{3}-\d$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W4qpvf/4)

**Explanation:**

- `^(\d)` matches and captures first digit after start in group #1
- `(?!\1{3}-\1$)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if we have 3 repetitions and a hyphen and another repeat of 1st digit.

Comment: Ow yes, this should be the accepted answer :-)

Comment: You are gracious but your working solution was posted well before my answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a [back reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), for example:

```
^(\d){4}-\1$
```

Comment: this works a few cases like 1111-1 but it's not working the cases like 1112-1 and I need vice versa also means it should not allow 1111-1 but it allows 1112-1 or 1111-1 like cases.

Comment: @HarinathaReddy Ah sorry, I just used the examples you gave indeed.